# Finding maximum value in a column in an Array and printing other corresponding value in the same row

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make program that finds the largest values in the second column of the array and prints this value (working program below), but then also prints the other corresponding value in the same row.

```
#include<iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };
   int i;
   float max = 0;

   for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
   {
      if(array[i][1] > max)
      {
         max = array[i][1];
      }
   }

   cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << max << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of saving the maximum value, also save the *index*.

Comment: Next time format your code properly before posting it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the comment by @JoachimPileborg to an answer.

1. In addition to saving the maximum value, save the index at which the maximum value is found also.
2. Print the values of the row from the index.

```
int main()
{
   float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };
   int i;
   float max = 0;
   int maxValueIndex = 0;

   for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
   {
      if(array[i][1] > max)
      {
         max = array[i][1];
         maxValueIndex = i;
      }
   }

   cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << max << endl;
   cout << "The other value in the array is " << array[maxValueIndex][0] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the row index:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };
    float max = 0;
    int row = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (array[i][1] > max)
        {
            max = array[i][1];
            row = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << max << endl;
    cout << "The other corresponding value in the same row is " << array[row][0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that your code finds the max assuming all positive values. If that is not the case, you should use this code instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };
    float max = array[0][1];
    int row = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (array[i][1] > max)
        {
            max = array[i][1];
            row = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << max << endl;
    cout << "The other corresponding value in the same row is " << array[row][0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also to find the index `i`, which correspond to the maximum element. After that you can use `cout` in the for loop.

```
#include<iostream>;


using namespace std;


int main()

{

float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };
int i;
int indmax;
float max = 0;

for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
{

    if(array[i][1] > max)
    {
        max = array[i][1];
        indmax=i;  
    }

}
cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << max << endl;
cout << "The row containing max values: ";
for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    cout << array[indmax][j] << " ";   
cout << endl;  
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With standard algorithm `std::max_element`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float array[3][2] = { { 16, 22 }, { 258, 1 }, { 42, 54 } };

    auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array),
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs[1] < rhs[1]; });

   std::cout << "The maximum value in the array is " << (*it)[1] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "other element in the array is " << (*it)[0] << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/EY884v)

**Note**: Code is in C++14, but may be rewritten in previous standard also.